# Show Div depending on select Value in foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

We have products that we display in a list.
For that we use a `foreach`.

We have approximately 25 products in our list. Here we try to hide the "add to cart" button, until a selection was made with a select option.

For each product separately that doesn't work as we have the same classes for each product.

With following script we have no success. Loading takes ages and changing the select does nothing, nor is the add to cart button hidden.

Here is our code so far:

```
    <script>
     $(document).ready( function() {
          $('.attribute_select').bind('change', function (e) { 
            if( $('.attribute_select').val() == 'choose') {
              $('#add_to_cart').hide();
            }
            else if( $('.attribute_select').val() != 'choose') {
              $('#add_to_cart').show();
            }         
          }).trigger('change');
        });
    </script>


    {foreach from=$products item=product name=products}

    <fieldset class="fs_1">
        <select name="s_name1" id="attribute_combination" class="attribute_select">
            <option value="choose" selected="selected">CHOOSE....</option>
            <option value="1" >1</option>
            <option value="2" >2</option>
        </select>
     </fieldset>

    <div id="add_to_cart}">
    <a class="" href="..." data-id-product-attribute="{$product.id_product_attribute|intval}" data-id-product="{$product.id_product|intval}" ></a>
    </div>
    {/foreach}
```

Comment: [___There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.___](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Comment: Use `class` instead of `id` and use `this` context in `handler` function...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/mxef3879/1/

Comment: Rayon the id are not the same, we add _{$id_product} to unify. But we are not familar with javascript

Comment: you have a typo in your div's id. it should be `<div id="add_to_cart">` but you have an errant `}` in there.

Comment: @Toni_Nutone – There is no need to maintain the `id` attributes, refer the provided fiddle....

Comment: We use following code now, but cant manage to show/hide only ht Add To Cart Button that belongs to the fieldset

   ` $(function() {
      $('.add_to_cart').hide(); 
        $('.ndk_attribute_select').change(function(){
         if($('.ndk_attribute_select').val() != 'choose') {
             $('.add_to_cart').show(); 
         } else {
             $('.add_to_cart').hide(); 
         } 
     });
     });`

Answer (score 1):

You have an invalid DOM ID which you will fail to match:

```
<div id="add_to_cart}">
```

Should be:

```
<div id="add_to_cart">
```

Answer (score 0):

We use following code now, but cant manage to show/hide only ht Add To Cart Button that belongs to the fieldset

```
$(function() {
     $('.add_to_cart').hide(); 
        $('.ndk_attribute_select').change(function(){
         if($('.ndk_attribute_select').val() != 'choose') {
             $('.add_to_cart').show(); 
         } else {
             $('.add_to_cart').hide(); 
         } 
     });
});
```

Any last Tipps?